# Removing odd spaces to get even number of spaces in a char array using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I implement it in javascript. The logic is actually to check the number of spaces that occur after a certain pattern in a character array and if the number of spaces are odd remove one space to make it even, and if the number of spaces are even leave it as it is.
for ex.

`* abc  \n   * abc`

in the above example I have 3 spaces between \n and *, what the output should be is 2 spaces between \n and *

`* abc \n  * abc`

the pattern I am talking about is the spaces occuring between * and \n.

Comment: @GuilhermeLemmi , thank you for pointing that out, added the example

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
console.log("* abc  \n   * abc".replace(/((  )+) ?/g, "$1"));
```

`"((  )+)"` catch even number spaces, then `" ?"` catch optional space if it exists. Finally `"$1"` replaces all found spaces (even or odd number) with caught even number of spaces.

Comment: nice answer! The only problem is if you have just one space after the pattern (in this case I think it should leave it with zero spaces, if I got the requirements right).

Comment: In that case just replacing `+` with `*` should do the job.

Comment: thank you , the * makes it perfect for my use case : )